# Access folder outside WAR in Websphere

Tags: java, websphere, war, ear

I have a requirement where I need to download a file from folder placed outside the project folder, so that we dont have to build EAR and deploy each time we need to change the file.

I am using WAS 7 and Maven for build.

If I specify direct path its able to download without any concern,But I need to deploy the EAR in QA env so I need to use relative path irrespective of env.

Comment: you can use a properties file to set the path. So, in QA env, you only need to change this property and not the java code.

Comment: will it be absolute path of QA?? like I have provided in DEV env
FILE_PATH=C:/WASProfiles/K61EDIAG_24_2/OnlineInstaller

Comment: that depends on you. Either give an absolute path or relative wrt WAS classpath. please let me know if this has helped you so that i will then add it as an answer.

Comment: I used String path= file.getAbsolutePath(); But it gave me C:\WASProfiles\K61EDIAG_24_2\..\..\..\workingdirectory\K61EDIAG... But my project in different folder C:\SVN\Dev\NR\A217032\K61EDIAG1\workingdirectory\K61EDIAG
I want the download folder close to Project directory

Comment: Create a properties file. Define a property, say, file_path = C:\SVN\Dev\NR\A217032\K61EDIAG1\workingdirectory\K61EDIAG  . In the code, get file_path from by reading the property.

Comment: It will work similar way in QA env?? In local it is working fine...For QA I have to contact admin..so which path I will ask him to specify in properties file?
I want some relative path(Not hardocde C:\SVN) to work so that it should work across all env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as Sampada posted in comments.

Added the FILE_PATH in properties file which is placed outside the EAR.